# PHP function returns ="" instead of /

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have got a wordpress instance and i want to set background image inline a html tag via php function.

The html is:

```
<div id="content" class="site-content" <?php echo get_background_for_single(get_the_ID(), is_single()); ?>>
```

The above html and php has the following output in browser:

```
<div id="content" class="site-content" style="background-image: url(" http:="" localhost="" wiese="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2019="" 06="" test.jpg");="">
```

In the functions.php i got:

```
function get_background_for_single($ID, $single) {

    if ($single == 1) {
        return 'style="background-image: url("' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url($ID) . '");';
    }
}
```

If i controll the output in a paragraph as follows, it is displayed correct:

```
<p><?php echo get_background_for_single(get_the_ID(), is_single()); ?><p>
```

It returns in a p tag:

```
style="background-image: url("http://localhost/wiese/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/test.jpg");
```

Why does the function return " ="" " instead of " / "? Perhaps it is a dump mistake, but i cannot see my mistake.

Comment: _“Why does the function return " ="" " instead of " / "?”_ - it doesn’t. Check the actual source code of the page, not the DOM view. This is simply what the browser made of the faulty HTML you gave it. `style="background-image: url("` - the content of that style attribute is `background-image: url(`, and then comes the ending delimiter `"` for that value. And then additional gibberish that is not part of that attribute value any more.

Comment: damn... you are right - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my function to the following is the solution:

```
function get_background_for_single($ID, $single) {

    if ($single == 1) {
        return 'style="background-image: url(&quot;' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url($ID) . '&quot;);"';
    }
}
```